# How to bypass base-8 number identification in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was doing an exercide I saw somewhere online that consisted of manipulating binary sequences (for example swaping every one by a zero and every zero for a one), at somepoint in the code, i wanted to print 0101 like this:

```
seq = 0101
print seq
```

And the output was 65 instead of 0101, I discovered this is because the 0 in the begginning of a integer identifies a base-8 number, how can I bypass this?

Comment: Don't put 0 at the beginning of a number.

Comment: Use Python 3 (then you get a syntax error, might is less confusing). Also, is `seq` supposed to be a number? Is the numeric value of "101" significant, e.g. used for calculations? If not, just make it a string, assuming that you want to print it as `0101`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. When you put 0101, it automatically translates to the value of oct(101). You can save it as binary:

```
seq = 0b101
```

but this does not keep the leading 0. Your best bet would be to save it as a string.

```
seq = "0101"
swapped = ''.join(['1' if b in '0' else '0' for b in seq]) # or maketrans
print(swapped)  # => 1010
print(int(swapped, 2))  # => 10
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it using it as a string it worked just fine!

Answer (score 1):

You should either use a string `"0101"` or use binary `0b0101`.
A string will print `0101` and the binary will print the binary number it represents (`5`).

Answer (score 1):

Python has binary literals, but you need to prefix them with `0b`. So your example should look like:

```
> seq = 0b0101
> print seq
5
```

You can also print the binary back:

```
> print bin(seq)
0b101
```